# HTML Not Rendering and Displaying as Plain Text on Frontend with Ninja Forms in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, plugins, ninja

I am experiencing an issue with Ninja Forms on my WordPress site where HTML is displayed as plain text on the frontend instead of being rendered properly. I have attempted to deactivate some plugins to identify if there's a conflict, but this has not resolved the issue.

The HTML for the form appears as plain text on the webpage. This includes anchor tags and line breaks which should normally be rendered by the browser. This was all working fine until recently.

I've tried deactivating each wordpress plugin, clearing the site cache, checking the ninja forms settings but with no luck.

What could be causing this issue where the HTML is not rendered and is instead displayed as plain text? Has anyone encountered a similar problem with Ninja Forms or any other form plugin in WordPress?

[image: The frontend]
[image: The ninja forms input in the backend]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused from the most recent update. I rolled it back to 3.7.3 and it fixed the issue